# Qt Android x86_64 Support

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, cross-compiling

When I installed Qt for Android it came with a kit for x86 and the 32-bit ARM ABIs, but no 64-bit ones. I noticed the Android NDK does contain the AArch64 and x86_64 compilers. Does Qt not support the newer architectures or is there a way in which I can build a Qt kit for these architectures myself?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This limitation are in the past now, use Qt 5.12 or above and you will can do it...

Source: https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.12/android-platform-notes.html

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not seem to come pre-compiled for Android x86_64 (see the "Qt Versions" tab to check it out). However, [this page of the wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/Android) seems to explain how to build Qt for Android, giving you the opportunity to make the Android x86_64 version by yourself, if it supports it.